# SQL programming

Tags: sql

Given the two tables below, write a select statement that will select all the country names that don't have exactly one default language.

Table A

```
id  country_code    country_name
1   CAN             Canada
2   USA             United States of America
3   MEX             Mexico
4   IND             India
5   ESP             Spain
```

Table B

```
id  country_code    language_code   is_default
1   USA             en              t
2   CAN             fr              t
3   CAN             en              t
4   USA             es              f
5   USA             zh              f
6   IND             en              f
7   MEX             es              t
8   IND             hi              f
9   CHL             es              f
```

Comment: And please show us what **you have tried** so far - SO is **NOT** a "gimme-ze-codez" code-writing service - **YOU** must show some effort yourself first! Where are you stuck? What is causing you problems?

Comment: I am new to sql. I tried this so far:

SELECT country_code, country_name
FROM Table A

SELECT country_code, is_default
FROM Table B
WHERE is_default = t

Comment: Please *do not* put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Join the tables and GROUP BY country_name. use a HAVING clause to filter the resulting rows to just those that have multiple language codes. You don't have to include the COUNT() as a column in order to use it in the HAVING clause.

```
select A.country_name
from TableA as A
inner join TableB as B
   on A.country_code = B.country_code
where b.is_default = 't'
group by A.country_name
having count(language_code) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to use an inner join on the "Country Code" to grab the country name. Also, you're going to have to do a count of iterations of the country name to determine the number of language_code rows present. Enjoy your Group By! :D